# CSS files not updating on virtual box

Tags: css, less, virtualbox, vagrant

I am using grunt & the roots wordpress theme on the bedrock wordpress stack powered by a lamp server running on virtual box. When I save a less file and it compiles to css it changes the css file locally on my IDE but when I refresh the page where I've got my site pointed to my servers IP, the file doesn't change. If I change HTML files it updates fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because sendfile was marked as 'on' in my nginx.conf file.

Solution:
sendfile off;